If I don't assume an induction hypothesis, is it still proof by induction?
While solving some linear algebra questions I came across the following problem.
Let $\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_k\in \mathbb{C}$ be distinct eigenvalues of $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{V})$. Let $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ be such that $u_i\in \mathcal{N}(T-\lambda_iId)$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.  Show that, $$u_1+\ldots+u_k=0\Rightarrow u_1=\ldots=u_k=0$$ Here $\mathcal{N}(.)$ is null(.).
My proof:
We prove by induction on $k$.
When $k=1$, $u_1=0\Rightarrow u_1=0$ is vacuously true. We note that, $u_1\in \mathcal{N}(T-\lambda_1Id)$. Which implies,
$$(T-\lambda_1Id)(u_1)=0\\
Tu_1=\lambda_1u_1\quad \text{(by linearlity)}$$
Because $u_1=0$, $Tu_1=0\Rightarrow \lambda_1u_1=0$ (Any linear transform maps $0$ to $0$).
Now, it is given that,
$$u_1+\ldots +u_k=0\\
\Rightarrow T(u_1+\ldots +u_k)=0 \\
\Rightarrow Tu_1+\ldots +Tu_k=0\\
\Rightarrow \lambda_1u_1+\ldots +\lambda_ku_k=0\\
\Rightarrow (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)(u_2-u_1)+\ldots+(\lambda_k-\lambda_1)(u_k-u_1)=k(-\lambda_1u_1)$$
We get the last equation by subtracting $\lambda_1u_1$ from each summand. We know $u_1=0$ and $\lambda_1u_1=0$,replacing them in the last equation, we get,
$$(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)u_2+\ldots+(\lambda_k-\lambda_1)u_k=0$$
Because each $\lambda_i$ is distinct,
$$(\lambda_2-\lambda_1) \neq \ldots \neq (\lambda_k-\lambda_1) \neq 0$$
Which implies, $u_1=\ldots=u_k=0$ [QED]
My Question is,
I have not defined an inductive hypothesis for this proof. Which is really new to me. Although the proof seems logically correct. Is this induction? I apologise if this seems like a dumb question.

To answer your actual question: No, if you don't have an induction hypothesis, it's not a proof by induction.  Purely as a matter of definition, induction requires some form of induction hypothesis.
That said, your argument has a couple issues...
First, you are using an inductive hypothesis in order to claim that $u_2 = \cdots = u_k=0$.  Otherwise, you cannot go from $(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)u_2 + \cdots + (\lambda_k-\lambda_1)u_k = 0$ to the conclusion.  The fact that you don't explicitly state the inductive hypothesis doesn't change the fact you're implicitly using one.
Second, and arguably more important, your argument isn't valid for a more insidious reason:  You cannot use the $k=1$ case's conclusion of $u_1 = 0$ inside the more general case.  If such an argument were valid, you'd be able to prove that $x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 0 \implies x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0$ for any elements of any vector space, not just eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues.  I hope you would agree this is far too strong.
Instead, you should state an inductive hypothesis and apply $T-\lambda_k\text{Id}$ to both sides of $u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_k = 0$.  You'll find something that looks an awful lot like the equation you found in your argument, but by a valid method.
